# New Key is not appearing in registry

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to Create a Key and adding 3 dwords to it to make it easier for me to add to multiple computers. But PS is not returning any errors when running but the key and the DWORDs are not appearing in registry. Here is my script

```
$registryPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Options\Mail"

$Name1 = "BlockExtContent"
$Name2 = "Send Pictures with Document"
$Name3 = "Receipt Response"

$value = "1"

IF(!(Test-Path $registryPath)){
    New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force | Out-Null

    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $Name1 -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null

    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $Name2 -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null

    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $Name3 -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
}
ELSE{
    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $Name1 -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null

    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $Name2 -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null

    New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $Name3 -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
}
```

I am unsure as to what I can change to make it work.

Comment: Can't duplicate. Your code works as expected for me. Perhaps you're running it under a different user account? HKCU is specific to each user

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my computer is so slow the registry took nearly 30 minutes to display the changes. Thank you Doug.